# How to get the data in this firebase structure? Error: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type model QuotationOrder

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried a few ways but I still cant retrieve the data inside. I might created the wrong model for my QuotationOrder Class as the it is 0,1,2... of orders. I'm new to Firebase. Would appreciate any help.

Here is the code and my model. Please guide me on whether i had created a correct model for it.

```js
List<QuotationOrder> quoteList;
quoteList = new ArrayList<>();

final DatabaseReference quotationListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("QuotationOrder")
                .child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getPhone());
        quotationListRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {                   Log.e("Query Refa",dataSnapshot.getRef().toString());
                Log.e("Query DataSa","\n "+dSnapshot.toString() );
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        QuotationOrder quote =  ds.getValue(QuotationOrder.class);
                        quoteList.add(quote);
                     Log.e("Query Refa",dataSnapshot.getRef().toString());
                Log.e("Query Refb",ds.getRef().toString());
                    Log.e("Query DataSb","\n "+ds.toString() );;
public class QuotationOrder {

   String itemID;
    String itemName;
    String itemPrice;
    String itemDescription;
    String itemCategoryType;
    String itemQuantity;
    ArrayList<Cart> order;

    public QuotationOrder() {
    }

    public QuotationOrder(String itemID, String itemName, String itemPrice, String itemDescription, String itemCategoryType, String itemQuantity, ArrayList<Cart> order) {
        this.itemID = itemID;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
        this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
        this.itemCategoryType = itemCategoryType;
        this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;
        this.order = order;
    }

    public ArrayList<Cart> getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void printOrders() {
        for (Cart carts : this.order) {
            System.out.println(carts);
        }
    }
```

**Update**
After following your suggestion, the size of arraylist quotelist is still 0. Also, i had added my model class. Please guide me on whether i had created a correct model for it.Thank you.
[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i1HP.png)

**[UPDATE2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i1HP.png)**
It seems the datasnapshot for the 2 loops has value from the picture below. The problem i am facing is to store it.If i am not wrong, it seems that the data cannot be stored in an arraylist? How to store it? My model went wrong? 
The error from Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(quote.getItemCategoryType())); is may produce null pointer exception

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfFBI.png

Comment: How is `cartRef` defined?

Comment: cartRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("QuotationOrder")
                .child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getPhone());
the getphone result is 123456

Comment: So to understand better, you want to get all `QuotationOrder` objects under all pushed nodes, right?

Comment: each uid have multiple items (0,1,2...). i want to get the data of each items under each order/uid

Comment: So you need all `(0,1,2...)` from pushed nodes, right?

Comment: yes sir. i need them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with some help from Alex and some tips from other post, i managed to figure out the answer to my question. Something actually went wrong in my model class when the itemPrice which is actually string is declared as int. Thanks for the help though, Alex.

```js
List<Cart> itemList;
itemList = new ArrayList<>();

final DatabaseReference quotationListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("QuotationOrder")
                .child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getPhone());
                
                 quotationListRef.child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getPhone())
                                            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                                        {
                                            for (DataSnapshot quotationSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                            {
                                                
                                                for (DataSnapshot productSnapshot: quotationSnapshot.getChildren())
                                                {
                                                   Cart cart = productSnapshot.getValue(Cart.class);
                                                    itemList.add(cart);

                                                    
                                                    for(Cart a: itemList)
                                                    {
                                                        Log.e("cart","\n "+a.getItemCategoryType() );
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                                        {
                                            throw databaseError.toException();
                                        }
```